# Data structure to manipulate long strings of bits

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitvector

In Python, what is the best data structure of `n` bits (where `n` is about 10000) on which performing the usual binary operations (`&`, `|`, `^`) with other such data structures is *fast*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Fast" is always relative :)

The [BitVector](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BitVector/3.0) package seems to do what you need. I have no experience concerning performance with it though.

There is also a [BitString](http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/) implementation. Perhaps you do some measurements to find out, which one is more performant for your specific needs?

If you don't want a specific class and do not need things such as slicing or bit counting, you might be ok simply using python's `long` values which are arbitrary length integers. This might be the most performant implementation.

[This qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147848/how-do-i-represent-and-work-with-n-bit-vectors-in-python) seems to be similar, although the author need fewer bits and requires a standard library.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to those mentioned by MartinStettner, there's also the [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray) module, which I've used on multiple occations with great results.

**PS:** My 100th answer, wohooo!

Comment: Might be even more performant than my suggestions since it's implemented in C. OTOH you might have some troubles installing it since it needs a working C compiler. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780127/installing-bitarray-in-python-2-6-on-windows for possible solutions :)